# How do I convert this string I read in from a CSV file to an integer?

Tags: python, string, integer

I read in this CSV file but I can not convert certain fields to integers, can someone please help.  I am receiving the error 'int' object is not iterable.

I tried several of the int functions.  Sorry, I usually work in Oracle/SQL not python.

```
import csv

inputfile = open("Popular_Baby_Names.csv", "r")

for line in inputfile:
    my_list = line.split(",")
    year = my_list[0]
    gender = my_list[1]
    ethnicity = my_list[2]
    first_name = my_list[3]
    count = my_list[4]
    rank = my_list[5]
    line = [rank.replace('\n','') for rank in rank]

    if year == "2014" and first_name == "Eric":

        int_count = int(my_list[4])
        print(int_count)
        sum(int_count)

inputfile.close()
```

Comment: Your int conversion works fine, but what are you trying to achieve by calling sum() on an int ?

Comment: Which line does the error complain about?  Show your complete error message.  A sample CSV file to try your code would help.  Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why aren't you using the `csv` module you imported to read the file?

Comment: I am trying to return those four rows and then sum up the count column.  Sorry, I know it is a dumb question in a way, I am an Oracle DBA and do some PL/SQL but don't know Python.  I'm trying to help a few students learn Python.

Comment: Sorry, here is the complete error message. It is line 19.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SH\Midterm\Question 98.py", line 19, in <module>
    sum(int_count)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable